Stress concentration factor for unfilleted rectangular bar in tension
Does anyone know if there exists a graph that includes the case where r = 0mm. Or is it the case that the stress concentration factor emerges for values of r more than 0.025mm?


At r=0 that is 90 degrees and is, so often, the cause of cracking and subsequent failure...

Stress concentration factor for $r=0$ is simply $\infty$. In reality, there will always be a radius even if very small.
